# FBSDKShareDialog line break in contentDescription

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift2, facebook-ios-sdk

So, using Facebook iOS SDK I'm creating share dialog with some url, title and message. Here's my code:

```
    let shareText = "Some text\n\nSome more text"

    let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com")
    content.contentTitle = "Share title!"
    content.contentDescription = shareText

    let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    dialog.mode = .FeedWeb
    dialog.shareContent = content
    dialog.fromViewController = self
    dialog.delegate = self
    dialog.show()
```

Dialog shows with all content provided except of line break not working (\n). I also tried < br> (without space). Why it doesn't work? How can I fix this?

Comment: Facebook removes line breaks from the description. (Probably from stopping people to get too “creative” with that.)

Comment: Thanks, damn I need some workaround then.